# How can I execute INSERT OVERWRITE over a table X if X is empty using Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, cloudera

I am trying to insert some values into a table `X` with partitions based on column `cx` if `X` is empty. I am trying to use a query like that:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE X PARITION(cx) 
SELECT DISTINCT ... 
WHERE ... OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT cx2 FROM X LIMIT 1)
```

But I am getting the follow error when I run that code:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]:
line 18:131 Unsupported SubQuery Expression '1': Only SubQuery expressions
that are top level conjuncts are allowed
```

Is there another alternative I can use to get the same expected behavior using only Hive's SQL?

Comment: Do you have subqueries elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, @GordonLinoff. No, just joins. That is the only subquery. Of course Hive may understand a SELECT nested to an INSERT as subquery, but SELECT itself has no others subqueries.

Comment: . . That is my guess.  So no subqueries are allowed at all.  Is the subquery really uncorrelated, so you are just checking if rows exist in the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, your comment give me some insight. I created a temporary table with the following code: `CREATE TABLE TABLE TMP_X_ AS SELECT * FROM X LIMIT 1`. Based on that table I added the condition OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TMP_X_)`. Now, if there is no rows in table `X` all resulted rows will be inserted, otherwise just rows respecting the first part of the condition will be inserted. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` in hive **should be correlated**. Like this

```
select * from a
where EXISTS (select 1 from x where x.col=a.col) --correlated condition
```

The same you can achieve using joins (suppose join key is not duplicating):

```
--checking NOT EXISTS
select * from a
         left join X on x.col=a.col  --same condition like in correlated EXISTS  query
where x.col is null --not exists

--checking EXISTS can be done using INNER JOIN:
select * from a 
         inner join x on x.col=a.col --same condition like in correlated EXISTS query

--checking EXISTS can be done using LEFT SEMI JOIN:
select * from a 
         left semi join x on x.col=a.col

--Insert into table X only if partition is empty (JOIN):
insert overwrite table X partition(p)
select col1, col2, p--partition col
  from Y 
        left join (select distinct p from X) x1 on y.p=x1.p
 where x1.p is null

--Insert into table X only if partition is empty (EXISTS):
insert overwrite table X partition(p)
select col1, col2, p--partition col
  from Y 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from X x1 where x1.p=Y.p)
```

Comment: Thank you, @leftjoin. It is true, but that query has not the same semantic effect that my issue requires.

Comment: @LucasVenezianPovoa Edited, added more examples, try also  to add limit 1 to the last EXISTS subquery

Comment: I tried that but without success. `... FROM T1 dc
JOIN T2 cli on (cli.a = dc.a)
JOIN T3 cc ON (cc.b = dc.b AND)
WHERE 1 = 1 OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T4 tmp WHERE tmp.c = dc.c LIMIT 1);`. For that statement I got the error: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: line 19:10 Unsupported SubQuery Expression '1': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed`.

Comment: @LucasVenezianPovoa please provide the whole query

Comment: my whole just starts with a `SELECT dc.c1 ...`. Then `SELECT dc.c1 FROM T1 dc JOIN T2 cli on (cli.a = dc.a) JOIN T3 cc ON (cc.b = dc.b AND) WHERE 1 = 1 OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T4 tmp WHERE tmp.c = dc.c LIMIT 1);`